# Haskell list help!

Tags: haskell

I'm struggling with Haskell programming.

I've got the list below and I want to make it stack on each other, so it'd be like 3 x 4 pixel image. eg:

[image: pixel image]

and how can I change the value of the first row or second ...
eg: say like I want to make it darker or whiter (0 represents black and 255 represents white)

```
type Pixel = Int
type Row = [Pixel]
type PixelImage = [Row]
print :: PixelImage 
print = [[208,152,240,29],[0,112,255,59],[76,185,0,152]]
```

The code I've got here does not stack the list and I don't know how to stack it.

Please help, I'm really struggling with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't really a discernable question here. Have you made an attempt that isn't working? Are you asking for a general approach?

Comment: yes i'm asking for help, cos i don't know how to do it, since i'm very new to haskell

Comment: Give us an example of the output you want for a given input.

Comment: don't know how to do what? output a list? do you want to print the numeric values or output an img format of some kind?

Comment: @Dave and Claudiu: I would like the result to be something like

[[208,152,240,29],
 [0,112,255,59],
 [76,185,0,152]]

Also i would like to be able to change the value of the row as well eg:
[[0,0,0,255],
 [0,112,255,59];
 [76,185,0,152]]

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a name other than `print` for your image to avoid collisions with the Prelude's `print`.

```
type Pixel = Int
type Row = [Pixel]
type PixelImage = [Row]

img :: PixelImage 
img = [[208,152,240,29],[0,112,255,59],[76,185,0,152]]
```

This is an inefficient representation, but it will do for a learning exercise.

You could print a `PixelImage` with the rows stacked on top of one another with a few imports at the top of your source and an I/O action:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List
import Text.Printf

printImage :: PixelImage -> IO ()
printImage img =
  forM_ img $ putStrLn . intercalate "  " . map (printf "%3d")
```

That may look intimidating, but everything there is familiar. The word order is just a little funny. For each `Row` in the `PixelImage` ([`forM_`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html#v%3AforM_), a lot like a `for` loop in other languages) we print (with [`putStrLn`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn)) the list of `Pixel` values separated by two spaces (thanks to [`intercalate`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v:intercalate)) and left-padded with spaces to make uniform 3-character fields ([`printf`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Text-Printf.html#v:printf)).

With the image from your question, we get

```
ghci> printImage img
208  152  240   29
  0  112  255   59
 76  185    0  152
```

Haskell lists are *immutable*: you cannot modify one in-place or destructively. Instead, think of it in terms of making a different list that's identical to the original except for the specified row.

```
modifyRow :: PixelImage -> (Row -> Row) -> Int -> PixelImage
modifyRow img f i = map go (zip [0..] img)
  where go (j,r) | i == j    = f r
                 | otherwise = r
```

This gives your function a chance to fire for each `Row` in the `PixelImage`. Say you want to zero out a particular row:

```
ghci> printImage $ modifyRow img (map $ const 0) 0
  0    0    0    0
  0  112  255   59
 76  185    0  152
```

Reversing a row is

```
ghci> printImage $ modifyRow img reverse 0
 29  240  152  208
  0  112  255   59
 76  185    0  152
```

In another language, you might write `img[2] = [1,2,3,4]`, but in Haskell it's

```
ghci> modifyRow img (const [1..4]) 2
[[208,152,240,29],[0,112,255,59],[1,2,3,4]]
```

That usage isn't terribly evocative, so we can defined `setRow` in terms of `modifyRow`, a common technique in functional programming.

```
setRow :: PixelImage -> Row -> Int -> PixelImage
setRow img r i = modifyRow img (const r) i
```

Nicer:

```
ghci> printImage $ setRow img [4,3,2,1] 1
208  152  240   29
  4    3    2    1
 76  185    0  152
```

Maybe you want to scale the pixel values instead.

```
scaleRow :: (RealFrac a) => PixelImage -> a -> Int -> PixelImage
scaleRow img x i = modifyRow img f i
  where f = let clamp z | z < 0     = 0
                        | z > 255   = 255
                        | otherwise = truncate z
              in map (clamp . (x *) . fromIntegral)
```

For example:

```
ghci> printImage $ scaleRow img 0.5 1
208  152  240   29
  0   56  127   29
 76  185    0  152
```

Adding `scaleImage` to apply a scaling factor to each `Pixel` in a `PixelImage` means a bit of refactoring to avoid repeating the same code in multiple places. We'd like to be able to use

```
scaleImage :: (RealFrac a) => a -> PixelImage -> PixelImage
scaleImage x = map $ scaleOneRow x
```

to get, say

```
ghci> printImage $ scaleImage 3 img 
255  255  255   87
  0  255  255  177
228  255    0  255
```

This means `scaleOneRow` should be

```
scaleOneRow :: (RealFrac a) => a -> Row -> Row
scaleOneRow x = map (clamp . (x *) . fromIntegral)
```

which promotes `clamp` to a toplevel function on `Pixel` values.

```
clamp :: (RealFrac a) => a -> Pixel
clamp z | z < 0     = 0
        | z > 255   = 255
        | otherwise = truncate z
```

This in turn simplifies `scaleRow`:

```
scaleRow :: (RealFrac a) => PixelImage -> a -> Int -> PixelImage
scaleRow img x i = modifyRow img (scaleOneRow x) i
```

Comment: sorry, how if i want to scale the whole image like from the first pixel of the first row to the last pixel of the last row? i'm very bad at this haskel. please...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple list manipulation for you.

```
import Prelude

get :: Int -> [a] -> a
get 0 (x : xs) = x
get i (x : xs) = get (i - 1) xs
get i [] = error "get: i is not in list"
```

ghci

```
*Main> get 1 (get 2 ["what", "is", "up", "man?"])
'p'
```

To set stuff you can use

```
set :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
set 0 t (x : xs) = (t : xs)
set i t (x : xs) = [x] ++ (set (i - 1) t xs)
set i _ [] = error "set: i is not in list"
```

with a command like

```
set 2 (set 1 't' $ get 2 ["what", "is", "up", "man?"]) ["what", "is", "up", "man?"]
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: `get` is equal to `flip (!!)`, by the way.

Comment: @yatima - I know, but the guy didn't even seem to know simple list manipulations.  Better in my opinion to to show somebody at that stage the code then just hand off a pre-built method.